# Join with has_may custom Relationship and has_may relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

We want to join User model with Tasks Model.I have two role in User Model we want to Tasks with user.In my User model two relationship with Task Model like :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :tasks,:dependent=>:destroy 

  has_many :manager_tasks, :class_name => 'Task',:foreign_key =>  'manager_id',dependent: :destroy 

end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  belongs_to :manager ,:class_name => 'User',:foreign_key => 'manager_id' 

end
```

we need to search with both user contact.But it works only one relationship user or manager not working on both.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: But the user and manager are the same not? So what you mean with search in both?

Comment: I have a contact in user table.we show list of tasks where we show contact of both user and manager from user table and search with contact.But it's work only one relationship.If we apply Task.joins([:user,:manager]) it gives the record of user only not driver in like query.